# Data from Firebase not displayed on RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display from data from my Firebase database but I'm getting the following: 
[my recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbZT3.jpg)

[Firebase database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWPNX.png)

I've been looking up different solutions but I still keep returning to the same problem. I'm fairly new to Android and programming in general so any help would be appreciated. Here is the relevant code.

LogbookFragment:

```
public class LogbookFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView textView;
private CardView cardView;
private String assessment;
private String details;

private RecyclerView rv;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

private List<Assessment> skillsList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "position";

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static LogbookFragment newInstance(int position) {
    LogbookFragment fragment = new LogbookFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public LogbookFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logbook, container, false);

    Context context = getActivity();
    cardView = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    final RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(skillsList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    initializeData();

    return rootView;
}

private void initializeData(){
    skillsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/assessments");

    final RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(skillsList);


    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());

            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (int i = 0; i<42; i++) {
                    assessment = postSnapshot.child("assessment").getChildren().toString();
                    details = postSnapshot.child("details").getChildren().toString();

                    skillsList.add(new Assessment(assessment, details));
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

RVAdapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.AssessViewHolder> {



public static class AssessViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView assessName;
    TextView pracName;

    AssessViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        assessName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.assessment);
        pracName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.details);

    }
}

List<Assessment> skill;

RVAdapter(List<Assessment> skills){
    this.skill = skills;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public AssessViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlogbook, viewGroup, false);
    AssessViewHolder avh = new AssessViewHolder(v);
    return avh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AssessViewHolder assessViewHolder, int i) {
    assessViewHolder.assessName.setText(skill.get(i).assessment);
    assessViewHolder.pracName.setText(skill.get(i).details);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return skill.size();

}
```

}

Assessment class:

```
public class Assessment {
String assessment;
String details;

Assessment(String assessment, String details) {
    this.assessment = assessment;
    this.details = details;

}

public String getAssessment() {
    return assessment;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}
```

Comment: The problem might be the fact that you only add data to the `skillsList` AFTER you had already initialized your adapter - and since the `skillsList` is empty at first, there's nothing to display. This also means that the lines `skillsList.add(new Assessment(assessment, details));
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for no effect. You should add a method in your Adapter that accepts `skillsList` and then update the underlying data. After calling that method, you can then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, The problem might be the fact that you only add data to the `skillsList` **AFTER** you had already initialized your adapter - and since the `skillsList` is empty at first, there's nothing to display.
So since you are not actually change the underlying data but rather initializing the adapter with the first initial data - these are the changes you should make to your `initializeData()` method:

```
private void initializeData(){
    skillsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/assessments/skills");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());

            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (int i = 0; i<42; i++) {
                    assessment = postSnapshot.child("assessment").getValue().toString();
                    details = postSnapshot.child("details").getValue().toString();
                    //here you add the assessment object to the list
                    skillsList.add(new Assessment(assessment, details));                    
                }

            }
            //at this point you have looped through all the "children" - 
            //now you are ready to initialize the adapter
            RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(skillsList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter));
            //commented out: no need to call this now - since you have not made any changes to the data
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I get data displayed in the recyclerview but they are not strings.  I'm getting the following: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YbZT3.jpg

Do you think anything can be done for this?

Comment: Hi, this is good progress, at least your List is displaying - I think you might have a problem with the line `postSnapshot.child("details").getChildren()..`, according to your data structure - do you have a value for `details` or do you have some more children under `"details"` - if not, then you can simply get values for both `details` and `assessment`. I have updated my answer - please try it out.

Comment: Alright, I've tried to change from .getChildren() to .getValue() but the app now crashes as it loads the data. 

I get this error now: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at athena.sentineljs.com.athena.LogbookFragment$1.onDataChange(LogbookFragment.java:85)

Comment: Can you please show me the screenshot of your data as it is on Firebase? This will help me understand how the code should look to look the values up.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a screenshot of my Firebase database. You can also find it here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gWPNX.png

Comment: Looking at your data structure, can you please change your URL **FROM** this : `"https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/assessments"` **TO** this: `"https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/assessments/skills"` - updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Wow, it's finally displaying properly. Thank you so much for your time and help, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think these two lines here are causing the issue

```
 assessment = postSnapshot.child("assessment").getChildren().toString();
 details = postSnapshot.child("details").getChildren().toString();
```

As per firebase documents you should retrive your value by calling the

```
getValue()
```

method not

```
toString();
```

As I don't know how your assesment and details data is . if it is a single value then

```
assessment = postSnapshot.child("assessment").getValue(String.class);
     details = postSnapshot.child("details")..getValue(String.class);
```

would do the trick.

For more information go [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I've tried that out and read the docs but now there is nothing in my recyclerview. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of your https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/assessments so that I can see the data schema

Comment: I've just edited the answer with a screenshot. You can also find it here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gWPNX.png

Comment: I've just gave it a go. I'm afraid that there is still no data in my recyclerview.

Comment: Hey, I've just managed to display the data properly based on the comments in the above answer. Thank you so much for your help and effort though, it is much appreciated. :)